# Changing Storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to switch from Main.storyboard to Main2.storyboard.
Main.storyboard is connected to ViewController.swift and Main2.storyboard is connected to Main2.swift

In ViewController.swift I have a button to switch to Main2.stoaryboard

```
@IBAction func btnSwitchStoryboard(sender: AnyObject) {
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main2", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main2")

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The problem is: When I press the button, the Main2.storyboard comes up from the button and goes down after one second, that I am back on Main.storyboard.

How is it possible to stay at Main2.storyboard?

*I am developing on iOS 9.2 / xCode 7.2.1 / Swift*

Comment: And goes down? Do you call a dismiss somewhere?

Comment: on some other buttons I have to delay a alert message which should be dismissed but I think its not a problem for changing the storyboard `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` - but this is line is inside the button actions func

Comment: Two questions 1. Why are you using 2 Storyboards when 1 is sufficient? 2. do you have some code that dismisses the your Viewcontroller?

Comment: I think you should more study about UIStoryBoard. You cannot changes the target StoryBoard rather than you can choose UIViewController from different StoryBoard.

Comment: @Larme - I had a dismissViewControllerAnimated in the Main2.swift which causes the problem

Comment: Put breakpoints on any dismissViewController and check if those lines get called

Comment: yeah I found a solution: I created an `let alert` and dismissed it with `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated ` instead of `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated `

Comment: Please don't post the solution in your question. A solution should be posted *as an answer*. You can post your own answer, it's perfectly ok. :) Also, note that you had a typo in your edited solution, both names were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION:** I used to dismiss `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` instead of `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated` to dismiss an `let alert`